# How to check for Estimated time reamaining in libtorrent python?

Tags: python, libtorrent

How can I check the estimated time to download a torrent using libtorrent python

```
while (handle.status().state != lt.torrent_status.seeding):
    s = handle.status()
    state_str = ['queued', 'checking', 'downloading metadata', 
            'downloading', 'finished', 'seeding', 'allocating']
    print ('%.2f%% complete (down: %.1f kb/s up: %.1f kB/s peers: %d) %s ' % \
            (s.progress * 100, s.download_rate / 1000, s.upload_rate / 1000, \
            s.num_peers, state_str[s.state] ))
```

I can't find any resources related to this

But I think it is not as simple as just adding

```
s.remaining_time
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many bytes are left to be downloaded, and you know the download rate, you can compute the estimated remaining time by:

bytes_left / bytes_per_second

Answer (score 1):

This should calculate remaining time:

```
import datetime

def get_eta(status):
  remaining_bytes = status.total_wanted - status.total_wanted_done
  if remaining_bytes >= 0 and status.download_rate > 0:
    eta_sec = remaining_bytes/status.download_rate
    return f"Estimated: {time_str(eta_sec)}"
  return ""

status = handle.status()
eta = get_eta(status)
```